# Changing Java Date one hour back

Tags: java, date

I have a Java date object:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

This will give the current date and time. Example:

```
Thu Jan 12 10:17:47 GMT 2012
```

Instead, I want to get the date, changing it to one hour back so it should give me:

```
Thu Jan 12 09:17:47 GMT 2012
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: is there any `mktime` equivalent in java? subtract 60 minutes from it?

Answer (score 308, accepted):

**java.util.Calendar**

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// remove next line if you're always using the current time.
cal.setTime(currentDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
Date oneHourBack = cal.getTime();
```

**java.util.Date**

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000);
```

**org.joda.time.LocalDateTime**

```
new LocalDateTime().minusHours(1)
```

**Java 8: java.time.LocalDateTime**

```
LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(1)
```

**Java 8 java.time.Instant**

```
// always in UTC if not timezone set
Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS));
// with timezone, Europe/Berlin for example
Instant.now()
       .atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"))
       .minusHours(1));
```

Comment: Just be vary of the fact that there is Calendar.HOUR which works with 12 hour clock and Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY for 24 hour clock: http://chintat.blogspot.ca/2006/05/calendarhour-vs-calendarhourofday.html

Comment: Would the first solution with Calendar work if the time is midnight of one day and you want an hour early which is 11pm the previous day?

Comment: @GeorgeArokiam yes it would

Comment: Woow! This is a perfect short answer for most alternatives.

Answer (score 74):

Similar to @Sumit Jain's solution

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000);
```

or

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));
```

Comment: Way better solution. Calendar instance creation looks like overkill in this particular application.

Comment: @cosmolev Calendar is overkill in most examples I find.

Comment: @Stoan I have added a more readable example.  You should note that Calendar is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10));` 

This should be 10 minutes behind?

Answer (score 26):

## tl;dr

In [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

```
Instant.now().minus( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS )
```

Or, zoned:

```
Instant.now()
       .atZone( ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .minusHours( 1 )
```

## Using java.time

Java 8 and later has the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built-in.

## `Instant`

If you only care about UTC (GMT), then use the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now ();
Instant instantHourEarlier = instant.minus ( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | instantHourEarlier: " + instantHourEarlier );
```

> instant: 2015-10-29T00:37:48.921Z | instantHourEarlier: 2015-10-28T23:37:48.921Z

Note how in this instant happened to skip back to yesterday’s date.

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you care about a time zone, use the [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. You can start with an Instant and the assign a time zone, a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object. This class handles the necessary adjustments for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now ();
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdtHourEarlier = zdt.minus ( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + "\nzdt: " + zdt + "\nzdtHourEarlier: " + zdtHourEarlier );
```

> instant: 2015-10-29T00:50:30.778Z
>
> zdt: 2015-10-28T20:50:30.778-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> zdtHourEarlier: 2015-10-28T19:50:30.778-04:00[America/Montreal]

## Conversion

The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are now outmoded. Avoid them. They are notoriously troublesome and confusing.

When you must use the old classes for operating with old code not yet updated for the java.time types, call the conversion methods. Here is example code going from an Instant or a ZonedDateTime to a java.util.Date.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( instant );
```

…or…

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Hello sir, I still cannot find the proper way to make "time ago" for the Instant.

Answer (score 10):

Use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) - 1);
```

Answer (score 8):

Just subtract the number of milliseconds in an hour from the date.

`currentDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime() - 3600 * 1000));`

Answer (score 6):

Or using the famous [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime = dateTime.minusHours(1);
Date modifiedDate = dateTime.toDate();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use from bellow code for date and time :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       System.out.println("Current Date Time : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one day to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one month to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one year to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one hour to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one minute to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
       System.out.println("Add one second to current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one day from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one month from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one year from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one hour from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one minute from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

       cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -1);
       System.out.println("Subtract one second from current date : " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Output :

```
Current Date Time : 2008/12/28 10:24:53
Add one day to current date : 2008/12/29 10:24:53
Add one month to current date : 2009/01/28 10:24:53
Add one year to current date : 2009/12/28 10:24:53
Add one hour to current date : 2008/12/28 11:24:53
Add one minute to current date : 2008/12/28 10:25:53
Add one second to current date : 2008/12/28 10:24:54
Subtract one day from current date : 2008/12/27 10:24:53
Subtract one month from current date : 2008/11/28 10:24:53
Subtract one year from current date : 2007/12/28 10:24:53
Subtract one hour from current date : 2008/12/28 09:24:53
Subtract one minute from current date : 2008/12/28 10:23:53
Subtract one second from current date : 2008/12/28 10:24:52
```

This link is good : [See here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-date-time-date-manipulation-java/)

And see : [See too](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/subtract4hoursfromthetimeandprintoutthedateandtime.htm)

And : [Here](http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php)

And  : [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Lwb9CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT367&lpg=PT367&dq=Changing%20Java%20Date%20one%20hour%20back&source=bl&ots=1QBQ5oGB7C&sig=e7B5OOO8B4KSsvKgWKrScBviv38&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjksfvdp9nOAhWI0h4KHVfpA4Y4FBDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=Changing%20Java%20Date%20one%20hour%20back&f=false)

And : [Here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)

If you need just time :

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: FYI: This Answer uses troublesome old Date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using `java.util.Date`. The following code will subtract 1 hour from your date.

```
Date date = new Date(yourdate in date format);
Date newDate = DateUtils.addHours(date, -1)
```

Similarly for subtracting 20 seconds from your date

```
newDate = DateUtils.addSeconds(date, -20)
```

Answer (score 0):

To subtract hours, you need to use the `HOUR_OF_DAY` constant. Within that, include the number with the negative sign. This would be the hours you want to reduce. All this is done under the Calendar `add()` method.

The following is an example:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     System.out.println("Date : " + c.getTime());
       // 2 hours subtracted
   c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -2);
   System.out.println("After subtracting 2 hrs : " + c.getTime());
 }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Date : Sun Dec 16 16:28:53 UTC 2018
After subtracting 2 hrs : Sun Dec 16 14:28:53 UTC 2018
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `ZonedDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Your answer would have been a good one in 2012 when the question was asked, but frankly it’s a poor one for 2020. Also are you contributing anything that isn’t already in more than one other answer?

Answer (score -1):

Get the time in milliseconds, minus your minutes in milliseconds and convert it to Date. Here you need to objectify one!!!

```
    int minutes = 60;
    long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date currentDate = new Date(currentDateTime - minutes*60*1000);
    System.out.println(currentDate);
```

Comment: @Makky: I know things have changed. But its not a wrong answer!!!
Why do you tell this a wrong answer?
Did you see the accepted answer fully?

Comment: Why would you even answer to a question which is 5 years old and has accepted answer.

Comment: This Answer provides no value beyond the existing years-old Answers. And this Answer unwisely uses terrible old date-time classes that have been supplanted for years by the java.time classes. Another problem: this Answer ignores the issue of time zone, and shows code that will use the JVM’s current default time zone while the Question asked for GMT/UTC. See the later parts of the [correct Answer by Kimi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833424/642706) or see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33404165/642706) for more discussion.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me instead using format .To work with time just use parse and toString() methods

String localTime="6:11";
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(localtime)

LocalTime lt = 6:11;
localTime = lt.toString()

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question. The Question is about more than a time-of-day alone.