# Finding the last modified file older than 24 hours in Java

Tags: java, date

I'm wanting to send an alert if the latest modified file in a directory is older than 24 hours. I've used the tips from these two questions:

[How do I find the last modified file in a directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064694/how-do-i-find-the-last-modified-file-in-a-directory-in-java)

[Changing Java Date one hour back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833399/changing-java-date-one-hour-back)

and have come up with:

```
File dir = new File("/path/to/dir");

File[] files = dir.listFiles();
if (files.length == 0) {
    return null;
}

File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
   if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
         Date modifiedDate = new Date(files[i].lastModified());
        return modifiedDate;
   }
}
Date currentDate = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(currentDate);
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
Date alertDate = cal.getTime();

if (modifiedDate.before(alertDate)){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

However I'm getting a "can not find symbol" modifiedDate. I realise that its because modifiedDate can't be seen by the last if statement but if I put that and the alertDate within the initial for loop then I get a "missing return statement".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like below;

```
public static boolean getLastModified() throws IOException{
    File dir = new File("C:\\temp\\lot_of_files\\logs");

    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0) {
        throw new IOException("No files to monitor in the dir");
    }

    Date modifiedDate = null;
    File lastModifiedFile = files[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
       if (lastModifiedFile.lastModified() < files[i].lastModified()) {
            modifiedDate = new Date(files[i].lastModified());
       }
    }
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(currentDate);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -24);
    Date alertDate = cal.getTime();

    if (modifiedDate != null && modifiedDate.before(alertDate)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is short term. I would personally look at developing the solution based on [Java WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I tried it that way and got a "Missing return Statement"

Comment: Hi Jerome, thanks that has worked. This code is actually just a little scriptlet that sits inside a off-the-shelf Java scheduling and folder watching program, so no need for the watch service. Thanks for the tip though :)